# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed when using redis.asyncio with pytest-asyncio

Tags: pytest, python-asyncio, redis-py, pytest-asyncio

I am trying to write tests for an asyncio-based Python app that uses Redis.

I reproduced the [Python code](https://redis.io/docs/get-started/document-database/#search-and-query) from the official [*Redis as a document database quick start guide*](https://redis.io/docs/get-started/document-database/) and turned it into tests:

```py
import pytest

from redis.asyncio import Redis
from redis.commands.json.path import Path
from redis.commands.search import AsyncSearch
from redis.commands.search.field import NumericField, TagField, TextField
from redis.commands.search.indexDefinition import IndexDefinition, IndexType
from redis.commands.search.query import Query
from redis.exceptions import ResponseError

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def redis():
    redis = Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
    yield redis
    await redis.aclose()

bicycle_ = {
    "brand": "Velorim",
    "model": "Jigger",
    "price": 270,
    "description": (
        "Small and powerful, the Jigger is the best ride "
        "for the smallest of tikes! This is the tiniest "
        "kids’ pedal bike on the market available without"
        " a coaster brake, the Jigger is the vehicle of "
        "choice for the rare tenacious little rider "
        "raring to go."
    ),
    "condition": "new",
}

bicycles_ = [
    bicycle_,
    {
        "brand": "Bicyk",
        "model": "Hillcraft",
        "price": 1200,
        "description": (
            "Kids want to ride with as little weight as possible."
            " Especially on an incline! They may be at the age "
            'when a 27.5" wheel bike is just too clumsy coming '
            'off a 24" bike. The Hillcraft 26 is just the solution'
            " they need!"
        ),
        "condition": "used",
    },
    {
        "brand": "Nord",
        "model": "Chook air 5",
        "price": 815,
        "description": (
            "The Chook Air 5  gives kids aged six years and older "
            "a durable and uberlight mountain bike for their first"
            " experience on tracks and easy cruising through forests"
            " and fields. The lower  top tube makes it easy to mount"
            " and dismount in any situation, giving your kids greater"
            " safety on the trails."
        ),
        "condition": "used",
    },
]

schema = (
    TextField("$.brand", as_name="brand"),
    TextField("$.model", as_name="model"),
    TextField("$.description", as_name="description"),
    NumericField("$.price", as_name="price"),
    TagField("$.condition", as_name="condition"),
)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def create_bicycle_index(redis: Redis):
    index = redis.ft("idx:bicycle")
    try:
        await index.dropindex()
    except ResponseError as e:
        pass
    await index.create_index(
        schema,
        definition=IndexDefinition(prefix=["bicycle:"], index_type=IndexType.JSON),
    )

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def bicycles(redis: Redis):
    for bid, bicycle in enumerate(bicycles_):
        await redis.json().set(f"bicycle:{bid}", Path.root_path(), bicycle)

@pytest.fixture()
async def bicycle_idx(create_bicycle_index, redis: Redis):
    index = redis.ft("idx:bicycle")
    return index

async def test_search_all_bicycles(bicycles, bicycle_idx: AsyncSearch, redis: Redis):
    res = await bicycle_idx.search(Query("*"))
    assert res.total == 3

async def test_search_jigger_bicycle(bicycles, bicycle_idx: AsyncSearch, redis: Redis):
    res = await bicycle_idx.search(Query("@model:Jigger"))
    assert res.total == 1
```

Unfortunately it throws the following errors:

```
E           RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py:539: RuntimeError
```

```
E           RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<test_search_all_bicycles() running at /home/duranda/devel/redis-pytest/test_redis.py:94> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py:180]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop

/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/streams.py:542: RuntimeError
```

The [full trace is available on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Y5stjued).

I tried to add the code below on top of my module to solve this error; without success.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

Note that you need to install `pytest-asyncio` and `redis-py` and to run a redis-stack server in order to test the above code, e.g.:

```bash
pip install pytest-asyncio redis
docker run -d --name redis-stack-server -p 6379:6379 redis/redis-stack-server:latest
```

I also added the following to `pytest.ini` in order to not having to use `@pytest.mark.asyncio`. Note that (
I also tried marking all my function with `@pytest.mark.asyncio` which did not help.

```ini
[pytest]
asyncio_mode = auto
```

Comment: Please show the full tracebacks

Comment: I edited the question and added the full trace.

Answer (score 2):

> There are issues with this answer and I am still looking for a better solution.

I was able to [fix this issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/38) by passing the `event_loop` fixture to the `redis` fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def redis(event_loop):
    redis = Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
    yield redis
    await redis.aclose()
```

However, this throws some warnings:

```
venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py:229
  /home/duranda/devel/redis-geospatial/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py:229: PytestDeprecationWarning: redis is asynchronous and explicitly requests the "event_loop" fixture. Asynchronous fixtures and test functions should use "asyncio.get_running_loop()" instead.
    warnings.warn(

app/tests/test_app.py::test_search_all_bicycles
  /home/duranda/devel/redis-test/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py:751: DeprecationWarning: The event_loop fixture provided by pytest-asyncio has been redefined in
  /home/duranda/devel/redis-test/app/tests/test_app.py:13
  Replacing the event_loop fixture with a custom implementation is deprecated
  and will lead to errors in the future.
  If you want to request an asyncio event loop with a scope other than function
  scope, use the "scope" argument to the asyncio mark when marking the tests.
  If you want to return different types of event loops, use the event_loop_policy
  fixture.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises from the difference in scopes between your fixtures and tests.

By default, `pytest-asyncio` creates a new event loop per function. If you wish to have asyncio session fixtures, your code must run with the same event loop as those fixtures, instead of recreating a new loop each function.

Per the [official guide](https://pytest-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/run_session_tests_in_same_loop.html), you can add this code to your `conftest.py` file (creating one if it doesn't exist):

> ```
> import pytest
>
> from pytest_asyncio import is_async_test
>
>
> def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
>     pytest_asyncio_tests = (item for item in items if is_async_test(item))
>     session_scope_marker = pytest.mark.asyncio(scope="session")
>     for async_test in pytest_asyncio_tests:
>         async_test.add_marker(session_scope_marker)
> ```

This ensures all tests run with the same event loop.

Comment: I tried this as well as marking all my tests with `pytest.mark.asyncio(scope="session")` but it did not solve the issue.